# How to show profile link on top header menu ? profile_edit_path giving error in applications.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a profile resources with edit_profile_path

now I am trying add the link of it on a sitewide menu hence adding the link on application.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'My Profile', edit_profile_path %>
```

All this looks very straight forward **but I am getting error**

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}
```

I did some searching and found this [Rails 3 - Nested Resources Routing - One to One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4753820/692622) but here the problem was nested routing which I don't have, here is what my rake routes give

```
edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)    profiles#edit
```

I am using devise but not sure this has anything to do with it though I do have

```
@profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])
```

in profiles.controller.rb

Any idea how to show the profile links on application.html.erb ? I am sure it is something  very small which I am missing out

**EDIT** - I have added `(@profile)` in link_to path, now I am getting this error -

`No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil}` ?

I am using devise and is using `@profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile]) in profiles_controller.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your profile model *belongs_to* the user one, the creation of a profile object requires a reference to which user object to associate it with. Therefore, you need to pass both the `current_user` and the `@profile`.

`edit_profile_path(current_user, @profile)`

Comment: Hi, now I am getting this error - No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} ? I am using devise and is using @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile]) in profiles_controller.rb

Comment: unfortunately @profile = current_user.profile.build(params[:profile]) is also not working

Comment: Thanks, this code worked edit_profile_path(current_user, @profile), can you tell me why we need current_user as an argument too ?

Comment: for sanity check, are you sure it works? Because I think it should be `edit_user_profile_path [current_user, @profile]`

Comment: [] is giving me error - syntax error, unexpected tLBRACK, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(', I am using Rails 3.2.8, but () is working fine. EDIT - OK, this is the best working code <%= link_to 'Profile', edit_profile_path(current_user) %>

Comment: Do you have an association `has_one :user` and `has_one :profile`?

Comment: Then I don't know how come `edit_profile_path(current_user)` works. The correct route should be `edit_user_profile_path(current_user, @profile)`.

Comment: sorry I meant I have belongs_to :user (in profile model) and has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy (in user model)

Comment: You don't have nested resources have you?

Comment: if ur profiles resource is nested inside user resources then u need to pass user object for whom the profile is to be updated. current_user should not be passed since u have specified that profiles resource is not nested. route has nothing to do with model relationship. if my profile model belongs to 10 different models, then considering the above, my route would be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pass `edit_profile_path` a param...

```
<%= link_to 'My Profile', edit_profile_path(@profile) %>
```

Comment: Hi, now I am getting this error - No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} ? I am using devise and is using @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile]) in profiles_controller.rb

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what `build_profile` does. If your User class has a profile, why not `@profile = current_user.profile`?

My guess is that the `@profile` you are using in your view is not a `class Profile` instance, therefore doesn't have an id. Hard to say without seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

u need to provide a object that exists in the database. building doesnt mean that the object has been saved. hence its passing id as nil.

```
edit_profile_path(@profile) #@profile needs to exist in db.
```